# How to setup a batch process in spring boot project for manipulated data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to setup a batch process in spring boot project for manipulated data.

I want to save some to the mysql.

So for that before saving I am doing few manipulations. like this.

```
{
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/myfile.geojson"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray features = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("values");
        for(int i=0;i<values.size(); i++){
            Object innerObject=values.get(i);
            String valueString = innerObject.toString();
            JSONObject nestedjson = (JSONObject) parser.parse(valueString);
            Object property = nestedjson.get("properties");
            JSONObject propertyObject = (JSONObject) property;
            String id = propertyObject.get("id").toString();
            String value = propertyObject.get("value").toString();
            myRepo.saveArea(id, value);
}
```

Now when I am reading about batch processing what I am getting is this : (after my customization)

```
public FlatFileItemReader<Model> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Model>()
            .name("myItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("Volts.csv")) // I have already reading above
            .delimited()
            .names(new String[]{"id", "value"})
            .lineMapper(lineMapper())
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Voltage>() {{
                setTargetType(Voltage.class);
            }})
            .build();
}
```

Now How I can manipulated the dat my self and save to DB through batch. which reader item shall I use.

In all the internet I got how to save csv to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Fort this use [Item processing](https://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/processor.html)

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Input, Output> {
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/myfile.geojson"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray features = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("values");
    for(int i=0;i<values.size(); i++){
            Object innerObject=values.get(i);
            String valueString = innerObject.toString();
            JSONObject nestedjson = (JSONObject) parser.parse(valueString);
            Object property = nestedjson.get("properties");
            JSONObject propertyObject = (JSONObject) property;
            String id = propertyObject.get("id").toString();
            String value = propertyObject.get("value").toString();
            myRepo.saveArea(id, value);
    }
    return output
}
```